# Images and other assets not showing from Contentful CMS API

Tags: javascript, contentful, astrojs

I'm working on a blog with Astro and Contentful.

The content is a rich text field I'm using the `contentful/rich-text-html-renderer` package to parse as shown in the Astro docs:

```js
    <article set:html={post?.body} />
```

Unfortunately, images and other assets are not showing at all.

How can I make the images show?

*Edit below:*

On further investigation, I can see that images are not coming from the Contentful API at all:

```js
---
import { documentToHtmlString } from "@contentful/rich-text-html-renderer";
import { Image } from 'astro:assets';
import { contentfulClient } from "../../lib/contentful";
import Layout from '../../layouts/Layout.astro'
import type { Post } from "../../lib/contentful";

export async function getStaticPaths() {

  const { items } = await contentfulClient.getEntries<Post>({ 
    content_type: 'post'
  })

  return items.map(item => {
    return {
      params: {
        slug: item.fields.slug
      },

      // props: {
      //   allPosts: item
      // } 
    }
  })
}

let post;

const { slug } = Astro.params;
// const { allPosts } = Astro.props;


try {
  const data = await contentfulClient.getEntries<Post>({
    content_type: "post",
    "fields.slug": slug,
  });

  const { title, author, coverImage, tags, dateModified, body, text } = data.items[0].fields;
  post = {
    title,
    author,
    coverImage,
    tags,
    dateModified: new Date(dateModified).toLocaleDateString(),
    body: documentToHtmlString(body),
    text 
  };

console.log("Body texts: ", body.content)

const getImages = text.content
  .filter(item => item.nodeType === 'embedded-asset-block')
  .map(item => item.content);


/*
Output:

Body texts:  [
  { data: {}, content: [ [Object] ], nodeType: 'heading-1' },
  { data: {}, content: [ [Object] ], nodeType: 'paragraph' },
  { data: {}, content: [ [Object] ], nodeType: 'paragraph' },
  {
    data: {},
    content: [ [Object], [Object], [Object] ],
    nodeType: 'unordered-list'
  },
  { data: {}, content: [ [Object] ], nodeType: 'paragraph' },
  {
    data: { target: [Object] },
    content: [],
    nodeType: 'embedded-asset-block'
  },
  {
    data: { target: [Object] },
    content: [],
    nodeType: 'embedded-asset-block'
  },
  {
    data: {},
    content: [ [Object], [Object], [Object] ],
    nodeType: 'paragraph'
  }
]
*/

console.log("Images: ", getImages)
// output: Images:  [ [] ]

} catch (error) {
  return Astro.redirect("/404");
}

const authorPic = post?.author.fields.authorImage.fields.file.url
```

Answer (score 1):

You may have forgotten to publish your assets. If you don't publish your assets, they won't show up even when embedded within a `RichText`.